# ucanaccess weird exception i cannot handle

Tags: ucanaccess, jackcess

I started using ucanaccess lately for connection to access database (obviously) and it all worked fine until now.
I'm starting to insert about 500,000 rows into the database.... when I reach about 400,000  the program stops.... the problem is I cant see the exception! i see this -

```
    at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.addOrRemovePageNumber(UsageMap.java:747)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.removePageNumber(UsageMap.java:337)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.allocateNewPage(PageChannel.java:354)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setNewPage(TempPageHolder.java:115)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.addOrRemovePageNumber(UsageMap.java:747)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.removePageNumber(UsageMap.java:337)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.allocateNewPage(PageChannel.java:354)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setNewPage(TempPageHolder.java:115)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.addOrRemovePageNumber(UsageMap.java:747)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.removePageNumber(UsageMap.java:337)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.allocateNewPage(PageChannel.java:354)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setNewPage(TempPageHolder.java:115)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.addOrRemovePageNumber(UsageMap.java:747)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.removePageNumber(UsageMap.java:337)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.allocateNewPage(PageChannel.java:354)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setNewPage(TempPageHolder.java:115)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.addOrRemovePageNumber(UsageMap.java:747)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap.removePageNumber(UsageMap.java:337)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.PageChannel.allocateNewPage(PageChannel.java:354)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.TempPageHolder.setNewPage(TempPageHolder.java:115)
at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.UsageMap$ReferenceHandler.createNewUsageMapPage(UsageMap.java:763)
```

I cant see where the exception began! 
it happened to me once already but after doing the "compress and repair" , it worked again...
now it does not.

Does anyone know whats going on with it?

Comment: It happens at the jackcess layer, so you should ask for their help(I mean, providing  the exception stack trace you have, it really looks like a stack overflow). What's the ucanaccess/ jackcess version?

Comment: poking around a little bit at this exception, it think you have a "non-standard" database (it looks like the internal tracking of the db is not handled in an expected manner).  how was this database created?

Answer (score 0):

check the following three things.

First of all, if you are using any IDE, make sure to increase the log buffer so that you will get to the start of this exception. May not offer much help, but will be better than looking at somewhere in-between.

Secondly, how much is the DB file size? There is a limitation on Access DB file size, which will result in such unconventional errors at times. Check that out.

Third - Do not open OR try to do something else with that particular DB while updating/inserting using *ucanaccess*. Doing so, most of the times results in this issue.